# Angular 11 css is not working when node_modules folder is symlinked

Tags: css, node.js, angular, symlink

I am working on several Angular projects which has same node_folder (with same node dependencies), so i made a symlink to new second angular project , it compiles successfully , but CSS is not working.

later i removed the symlink  and modified the angular.json with "../node_modules/.." pointing to node_modules folder which is on same level as project folder

- ../
- ./
- /node_modules
- /project1
- /project2

etc

still the project gets compiled , yet CSS is not working - is it possible to fix this and get CSS working with this way ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding NODE_PATH pointing to node_modules folder and modifying the angular.json accordingly solved the problem